# How to add multiplayer to my new unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am making a new game in unity and I am a newbie in this arena. I am trying to clone the game Among Us. I am done with the basic player movements, maps and tasks. all I need now to work with is implementing multiplayer. please tell me how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you going for. Like if you want to make Local multiplayer first then you can go with this :

https://connect-prd-cdn.unity.com/20210504/93a938b7-ee56-488f-b0b3-8b956c0a31fd/Unit%201%20-%20Bonus%20Features%20Solutions.pdf?_gl=1*gvcr20*_ga*MjA5NzMyMDg4Ny4xNjI0MDg3NjI1*_ga_1S78EFL1W5*MTYyNjUxODg0NS4xMy4xLjE2MjY1MTkwODYuNDA.&_ga=2.45597348.1066118217.1626406772-2097320887.1624087625

I recommend first passing through this as the online multiplayer can be a hard and time consuming work. But still if you want to go further, this can help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmPukdOsYQA

Thanks